# Css drag and drop grid with jquery and jquery ui has an empty space

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-float

I think this is probably a CSS issue, but i am not really sure
I have loaded an example to 
http://jsfiddle.net/paries/7CgZp/
The problem is why is there an empty box below widget5 and above widget 11.
I am using chrome , FF does not seem to load the resources at jsfiddle or i am doing it wrong.
I can not drag an element into that empty box either

Thanks for any help
Randy

Comment: Could you also paste your code in stack please?

Comment: `<li id="95" class="ui-state-default home-page-item" style="height:200px; width:200px; ">` height should be `100px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution.
this seems to work great
http://gridster.net

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was a height difference in `id=95` of the `li`'s
Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/7CgZp/8/

Comment: the goal was to have one that was twice as high as the others. And when i did that , it show that problem. So sorry you really did not fix the problem

Comment: ok, well you were asking in your question why there was a space. If you want the space to remain, I will take a look.

Comment: thanks, sorry about the confusing question. So i do not want the space but i want one of the other LI to fill the space. Does that make sense?